# How do you confirm a string only contains numbers in Swift?

Tags: ios, regex, swift

How can I check, if searchView contains just numbers?

I found this:

```
if newText.isMatchedByRegex("^(?:|0|[1-9]\\d*)(?:\\.\\d*)?$") { ... }
```

but it checks if text contains any number. How can I do, that if all text contains just numbers in Swift?

Comment: Try parsing it into an int. If there is anything other than int, it will throw an error.

Comment: How can I do it with a short way? @ShahiM

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Here is the solution you can get all digits from `String`.

## Swift 3.0 :

```
 let testString = "asdfsdsds12345gdssdsasdf"

 let phone = testString.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted).joined(separator: "")

 print(phone)
```

Comment: Will this NSCharacterSet include arabic type of numbers? I mean maybe user need only this type of numbers (1, 2, 3, 4, ...) but also keyboard may include such numbers (١٢٣). How can I check only (1, 2, 3)?

Comment: @СергейОлейнич, if you want to be sure about only specific characters are included in your set, you can define the character set by `+characterSetWithCharactersInString:` method. ([source](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCharacterSet_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSCharacterSet/characterSetWithCharactersInString:))

Answer (score 6):

you can use `"^[0-9]+$"` instade `"^(?:|0|[1-9]\\d*)(?:\\.\\d*)?$"`

This will accept one or more digits, if you want to accept only one digit then remove `+`

Comment: what about floating numbers? or negatives? are those not numbers anymore?

Comment: "^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?$" this will match the floating as well as intigers
if you want to accept only decimal then use "^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$"

Comment: indeed. that is why it is not clear why you recommend explicitly _not_ to use that.